# How to open another version of the same app Java?

Tags: java, swing

I added a method to my network chat system to connect to another server at the same time as having another connection open. The way I set it up works, except  it's not an independent instance of the system. When I close the main window, it closes all the other ones too. Is there any way I can open up a completely new instance of the login window?

Here's the code I am using:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String[] input = null;
        Login.main(input);
    }
```

Comment: When you say "window", you mean you are working with Swing? And you want when one Swing window is closed to keep another one running?

Comment: Yes, I am using JFrames, and I want to create just a whole new instance of the application, so when I close the one I opened at first, the others stay open.

Comment: Please clarify your problem and your question as all is still very muddy. Also, you generally don't want to swap JFrames. Instead swap JPanel views within a JFrame using CardLayout.

Comment: Or if you need to display a "login window" this will usually not be a JFrame at all, but rather a *modal* JDialog.

Comment: Okay, I am trying to do my best, but I am relatively new to programming, so I am not at the same level as you guys answering. I am trying to open a new instance of the same application. My problem is that when I open the application, it is still tied to the first application, so when I close that one, it closes both. Is there a way around that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution with good practice provided by @HovercraftFullOfEels in comments.

To cover your use-case only:

- You can maintain the list of created Windows(JFrame).
- Don't exit on close instead dispose.
- Remove the Windows from the list on closing.
- If no window present in the list then exit the system.

here is some sudo code:

```
    final List<JFrame> jframeList = new ArrayList<JFrame>();

    JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
    jframeList.add(jFrame);

    jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    jFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            JFrame jframe = (JFrame) e.getSource();
            jframeList.remove(jframe);
            if (jframeList.isEmpty()) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    });
```